# Storing a Dynamic Range in Range variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get unique values from dynamic F column and store it in an array. I am getting "Object Required error for my code while setting Selection variable to a dynamic range. Please help.

```
Sub UniqueFilter()
Dim tmp As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim Selection As Range
Dim lrow As Long
Dim str As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("14Feb19")
sht.Activate

'Set Selection = sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, 6), sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End   (xlUp)).Select

lrow = shData.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Selection = sht.Range("F2:F" & lrow).Select



If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
For Each cell In Selection
  If (cell <> "") And (InStr(tmp, cell) = 0) Then
    tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
  End If
Next cell
End If

 If Len(tmp) > 0 Then tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

 arr = Split(tmp, "|")

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line errors? and what is `shData`

Comment: You can just say `arr = application.transpose(range)` or use a `scripting.dictionary` and check it's `.exists` property to remove the dupes etc.

Comment: shData Is the sheet name and it errors out at "Set Selection =.." If I remove Set Selection it works fine but I need to capture this selection to loop throught the dynamic range.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work. Some cells are unique and some values are repeated, so I am trying to capture unique values and create an array.

Comment: Just `Set Selection = sht.Range("F2:F" & lrow)` will do I think

Comment: Ohgod, that was such a stupid mistake. How could I not see? Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Generally it's a sound move to avoid selecting or activating objects, and it seems that this error is a remnant of such behaviour.

Comment: Also, it's a good example of trying to avoid reserved words.   You were using a variable `selection` and recoding the `selection` which would left after your range `.select` in VBA's `selection` Good practice, is to abbreviate the data type before the variable, so `rngSelection` and `rngCell` etc.

Comment: Ya will take care. Thanks for your useful inputs :)

Comment: @Divya Roopam Take a look at my answer, it should be what you're looking for ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal without having to use **Selection** at all. 
Just copy the range content and transpose it into an array:

```
Sub UniqueFilter()
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim count As Integer

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("14Feb19")
    sht.Activate

    lrow = sht.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Copying and trasposing selected Range
    tmp = Application.Transpose(sht.Range("F2:F" & lrow).Value)

    'Cleaning from temp array all empty values
    count = 1
    For index = 1 To UBound(tmp, 1) - LBound(tmp, 1) + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr(1 To count)
        If tmp(index) <> "" Then
            arr(count) = tmp(index)
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

---

(special thanks to `@Nathan_Sav`, who helped simplifying the code)

Comment: This can be done like `arr=application.transpose(tmp)` ??

Comment: I tried but you'll get a `13, Type Mismatch` error, because the function expects to work with matrix, not arrays.

Comment: `Dim arr() as variant:arr=Application.Transpose(sht.Range("F2:F" & lrow).Value)` ?

Comment: Yes, with a small correction it works! I'm updating the code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, it works but it is taking blank cells as well. I need only cells with values in F column.

Comment: @Divya Roopam Ok, try this code. I've tested it on my Excel and it works. Let me know if it solved the problem. :)